# How can setState rebuild only AppBar?

Tags: flutter

I have a Scaffold in which AppBar I have an IconButton that I want to work like a switch: it changes its state when pressed.

Although easy to implement with a bool and setState, the whole widget is redrawn on setState, with the following:

```
actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.favorite, 
        color: estaMarcada ? K.color_highlight : K.color_background),
        onPressed: () { setState(() 
            {estaMarcada = not estaMarcada;});},
     ),
```

I'd like to redraw only the Icon (or the AppBar) but not the whole Scaffold.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make your IconButton inside Variable of Type Widget and switch his value(Type Widget) in Your SetState function.

Comment: Why? What's your purpose behind doing that? Because that probably won't work as you'd expect.

Comment: @Houssem, tried it, but all page is still redrawn. Do you have any code sample?

Comment: Rémi, I want the button color to represent its state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract your AppBar to a separate **StatefulWidget** and `setState()` in  there

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  MyAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyAppBar> createState() => MyAppBarState();
}

class MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Icon(K.icon),
          Text(K.title), 
        ]),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon:Icon(Icons.favorite, 
            color: appData.getMark() ? K.color_highlight : K.color_background),
          onPressed: () { 
            setState(() {
              appData.setMark();
            });
          },
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The extended widget must implement PreferredSizeWidget. Otherwise you will not be able to use this widget in Scaffold. Also, MyAppbarState cannot start with the underscore as you need to access it from outside.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your build() method for your scaffold has side-effects or makes a network call.  You should always construct your build() methods as if they might be called 60 times a second, so they should be fast and idempotent.

Comment: True if my setMark does any synchronous save

Comment: This sounds nice in theory, but sometimes Scaffold holds a widget like TabBar with 4 complex children. This TabBar widget is expensive to rebuild, but it manages its own state. In this case it is very reasonable to update the AppBar without calling setState() on the entire Scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DivinePaul, I did this:

```
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget {

  MyAppBar() : super();

  @override
  _MyAppBarState createState() => _MyAppBarState();
}

class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Icon(K.icon),
          Text(K.title), 
        ]),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon:Icon(Icons.favorite, 
            color: appData.getMark() ? K.color_highlight : K.color_background),
          onPressed: () { 
            setState(() {
              appData.setMark();
            });
          },
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. The extended widget must implement PreferredSizeWidget. Otherwise you will not be able to use this widget in Scaffold.